# Unix scripting commands to read a filename

Tags: shell, unix

can anyone tell me the difference between the below two??

```
FILENAME=`echo /var/data`
```

and

```
FILENAME=/var/data
```

in unix scripting.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: The first one unnecessarily creates an extra process to run the `echo` but the end result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Both variants will give you the same result.

The big difference is that the first variant, using commands inside a pair of backticks, gives you the possibility to perform more advanced commands than simple `echo`, and use the output from the command (or piped chain of commands) and assign that to the variable.

---

For example, lets say you have a command which give some lines of text of output, one line containing e.g. `Path: /var/data`. To get the path you could use the commands

```
command_with_output | grep "Path: " | sed 's/Path: //'
```

The above chain of commands searches the output of `command_with_output` for a line containing `"Path: "`, then removes the `"Path: "` part of that line.

Using the above chained command, together with the backticks you could then do

```
FILENAME=`command_with_output | grep "Path: " | sed 's/Path: //'`
```